# how to recursive Use of make with conditional in phony?

Tags: makefile

The folder arragment as below

```
./Makefile
./libft/Makefile
```

In ./Makefile, I used below and the result is make clean run 2 time in libft/Makefile.

```
clean :
    ${RM} ${OBJS}
    ${MAKE} clean -C libft
fclean : clean                       << reason
    $(RM) $(NAME) 
    ${MAKE} fclean -C libft
```

I tried to change it to

```
clean :
    ifdef WITH_FCLEAN
    ${RM} ${OBJS}
    else
    ${RM} ${OBJS}
    ${MAKE} clean -C libft
    endif

fclean:
     make WITH_FCLEAN=1 clean
```

But this never work, always error massage when issuse "make clean"

How do I make it work with condistional statment in PHONY?
or should I go other approach? put the statment outside of PHONY? how?

thank you

---

./libft/Makefile

```
NAME = libft.a
CC = gcc
CFLAG = -Wall -Wextra -Werror
SRCS = ft_isascii.c ft_isdigit.c ft_isprint.c ft_isalnum.c ft_isalpha.c 
OBJS = ${SRCS:%.c=%.o}
AR = ar rcs
RM = rm -rf

$(NAME) : $(OBJS)
    $(AR) $@ $^

.PHONY : all
all : $(NAME)

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAG) -c $< -o $@

.PHONY : clean
clean :
    $(RM) $(OBJS) 

.PHONY : fclean
fclean : clean
    $(RM) $(NAME)

.PHONY : re
re : fclean all
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What do you want `make clean` and `make fclean` to do?

Comment: I want make in ./Makefile do the clean/fclean up in folder ./  
and call the make in ./libft/Makefile clean/fclean.
So that they can do their own job.
the requiement is that in libft/ build and clean itself by its owned Makefile make command.

Comment: Could you show us `libft/Makefile`?

Comment: yes. I update on the opening question

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the drawbacks of recursive Make; it blocks the normal handling of prerequisites. You invoke two sub-Make processes, they know nothing about each other, so they are not aware that they both run `clean`.

The simplest solution is to modify the upper makefile, splitting the `clean` rule into two rules:

```
.PHONY: rm_objs clean fclean
rm_objs:
    ${RM} ${OBJS}

clean : rm_objs
    ${MAKE} clean -C libft

fclean : rm_objs
    $(RM) $(NAME)
    ${MAKE} fclean -C libft
```

A better approach is to do without recursive Make, but that is a more advanced exercise which you can attempt when you are ready.